# Fullcalendar move only by 1 day (prev/next) in week view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there a way in fullcalendar on the week view to move by 1 day (next/prev buttons) instead of jumping 1 week back and forth?

The reason behind is because when I create an event on the week view I am limited to the last day and can't prolong it to the next week...

Comment: If you are only working with one view you can alter the fullcalendar.js file itself.  I have figured out if you change line 7931 from `date.clone().startOf(this.intervalUnit).subtract(this.intervalDuration), -1` to `date.clone().startOf(this.intervalUnit).subtract(1)` the prev button works as expected.  However changing line 7939 from `date.clone().startOf(this.intervalUnit).add(this.intervalDuration)` to `date.clone().startOf(this.intervalUnit).add(1)` does nothing.  I will continue to try and get the add to work.

Answer (score 2):

They now have added [`dateIncrement`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/dateIncrement/) as a option.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'today prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'CustomW,CustomF,CustomS',
  },
  views: {
    CustomW: {
      type: 'timelineWeek',
      duration: { days: 7 },
      buttonText: 'Week',
      dateIncrement: { days: 1 },
    },
    CustomF: {
      type: 'timelineWeek',
      duration: { days: 15 },
      buttonText: '15 day',
      dateIncrement: { days: 4 },
    },
    CustomS: {
      type: 'timelineMonth',
      duration: { days: 30 },
      buttonText: 'Month',
      dateIncrement: { days: 10 },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Hi there, when I try this but with an agenda type view or basic week I can't move back to before 'today' any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out how to make this work for both subtraction and addition.  I had to alter the fullcalendar.js file itself which means there could be some other complications as I have not tested this beyond clicking the next and previous buttons.  I would not recommend doing this approach if you plan on utilizing more than one view.

**Force currentview to change on click**

Comment out lines 9741 - 9747 and 9759
This allows the currentview to change when clicking the next button even though you haven't actually left the currentview

**Previous Click**

Line 7931 needs to be changed to

```
date.clone().startOf('day').subtract(1)
```

**Next Click**

Line 7939 needs to change to

```
date.clone().startOf('day').add(1, 'day')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom view like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    center: 'month,basicWeekOneDay' // buttons for switching between views
},
views: {
    basicWeekOneDay: {
        type: 'basicWeek',
        duration: { days: 1 },
        buttonText: '1 day'
    }
}
```

});

Here is fiddle for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/raj20090/j99f7zqw/2/

Comment: how do the events rendered?

Comment: Right, however this is not exactly what I'm asking :)  I'd like to see several days (7 by default) and still be able to move the week by 1 day steps when pressing the prev/next buttons.